# install IIS managed module

Tags: iis

I have just migrated a web site from one server to another (by using the IIS export/shared configuration feature).

When I try to submit a post to my website, I get HTTP 503. When I go to the event viewer, I see an error that starts with:

> IISMANAGER_ERROR_LOADING_PROVIDER_TYPE IIS Manager could not load type
>   'Microsoft.Web.Management.Delegation.DelegationModuleProvider,
>   Microsoft.Web.Management.Delegation.Server, Version=8.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35' for module provider
>   'DelegationManagement_Current' that is declared in
>   %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\administration.config. Verify that
>   the type is correct, and that the assembly that contains the module
>   provider is in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC).

I found this post: [IIS Manager could not load type 'Microsoft.Web.Management](https://serverfault.com/questions/787941/iis-manager-could-not-load-type-microsoft-web-management), which explains that I need to install a missing module. The answer to that post says I should install the missing module by either downloading it from iis.net or using Web Platform Installer.

Can anyone give further details on how to install the module? I've tried searching iis.net and WPI for the type/assembly names, but I get no results.

The types and assemblies of the missing modules are:

type: Microsoft.Web.Management.Delegation.DelegationModuleProvider

- assembly: Microsoft.Web.Management.Delegation.Server

type: Microsoft.Web.Deployment.UI.PackagingModuleProvider

- assembly: Microsoft.Web.Deployment.UI.Server

type: Microsoft.Web.Management.Iis.Rewrite.RewriteModuleProvider

- assembly: Microsoft.Web.Management.Rewrite

Comment: I get exactly the same error when migrating from one server to another. I think the missing modules could be transferred from the old server to the new, but I still don't know how.

Comment: Another dev on my team decided to try recreating the website manually. (Create a new website in IIS and copy over the files from the old server). The website works, so I guess this module wasn't actually referenced in our code.